# xpath for email addresses, usual methods don't work

Tags: xpath

I am trying to extract the third email address from this website:
https://www.usvotefoundation.org/vote/eoddomestic.htm;jsessionid=278032F9EB8FD34A6E9AD4D8E4C0F456?submission=true&stateId=1&regionId=430369
(the one for the chief election official), but I have not been able to do so. I have tried:

`//*[@id="collapseEodContact"]/div/div/table/tbody[3]/tr[3]/td[2]/a`

`//a[starts-with(@href, "mailto")]/text()`

`//*[contains(text(), '@')]`

In fact, I don't seem able to pick up any of the email addresses on the page, while being able to pick up other information, including other href attribute links links.

What am I missing?

Comment: `//a[starts-with(@href, "mailto")]/@href`

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work either. I get a null, as with the other options.

Comment: Try this - (//a[contains(@href,'mailto')])[3] for the third email

Comment: Thank you! It did not work either, though. I may should mention I am using Scrapy's shell to test these xpaths, which then I'll use to scrape this website.